# Mercurial: Hg Status - Do you know how to report file name only (no path) on Windows OS?

Tags: mercurial

When I run Hg status I get a listing something like the following:

```
M proj\Content\Site.css
M proj\Views\DoThing\DoThing.cshtml
M proj\Views\MainThing\MainThing.cshtml
M proj\Views\GetThing\GetThing.cshtml
M proj\Views\ViewThing\Index.cshtml
M proj\Views\Home\Index.cshtml
M proj\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml
M proj\js\extra.js
```

Does anyone know how to run hg status and easily get just the filnames to be listed -- sans the path info?  Something like:

```
  M Site.css
  M DoThing.cshtml
  M MainThing.cshtml
  M GetThing.cshtml
  M Index.cshtml
  M Index.cshtml
  M _Layout.cshtml
  M extra.js
```

Or, if you have some quick way of piping this through some command-line thing like findstr or something which will easily and quickly strip off the path, let me know.

I need the final format shown.  Anyone?  Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Mercurial 3.5 installed (i.e. the most recent version as of the time of this writing), you can use the experimental status templates. Use `hg help status -v` to see if there's a `--template` option. If so, use:

```
hg status -T '{status} {path|basename}\n{if(copy, "  {copy}\n")}'
```

This is the normal `status` output, except that `{path}` has been replaced with `{path|basename}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use **sed**

Extract the file path and replace with file name

```
hg status | sed "s/ .*\\\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/ \1.\2/
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't have sed natively on Windows OS.